# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Environment option when building an app?

Tags: sencha-touch, ibm-mobilefirst

When you are doing a build and Deploy from Worklight 6.0 app (which uses Sencha Touch 2.3), which build environment option is considered. is it development, testing or production?

Reason I am asking this is because I need to make sure that Sencha is built using production option from Worklight.

Please help me to re-direct toward correct path. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in fact talking about preparing your application for production when using Sencha Touch, then this has got nothing to do with Worklight, but to your Sencha Touch settings. Worklight is not involves in this process what-so-ever.

Read online:

- http://moduscreate.com/preparing-for-sencha-touch-production-deployment/
- http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/guide/building
- google.com

---

Otherwise,

1) This has got nothing to do with the framework you are using (whether it is Dojo, jQuery Mobile, Sencha Touch or anything else, backbone.js, angular.js, whatever...). So lets take that out of the equation.

2) Worklight Studio, the tool that is used to produce the project artifacts, which are your .adapter, .wlapp file and generated project (in the case of WP8, BB6/7/10, Android and iOS) comes in 2 flavors:

- Developer Edition
- Consumer Edition

The difference between the two is, mostly, the existence of App Authenticity in the latter.
Other than that the two editions produce the same artifacts

If you are not an IBM customer, you are then using the developer edition, which allows you to build, deploy and test your application in Eclipse using a built-in Worklight Server.

If you are an IBM customer, you should be using the Consumer Edition. In this case you also get tools to install Worklight Server in an exteral application server, which then allows you to run your application in a QA/UAT/PROD environment.

So building in Worklight Studio is mostly agnostic to your environment... it will produce the artifacts that you need no matter the environment (see above, though, about App Authenticity).

Legally speaking, though, you must use the Consumer Edition  (= buy a license to use Worklight) if you ever intend on going public with your app (be it a B2C or B2E app).

Comment: Thanks Idan. So you mean to say Sencha Touch build is separate from worklight build, and we do not need to do any setting, except to change <script src="js/touch/sencha-touch-all-debug.js"> to </script> <script src="js/touch/sencha-touch-all.js"></script> in your app.html. Please confirm. Thanks

Comment: I would assume so, yes.